# perforce streams should have same branching hierarchy for parent & child streams.

Tags: perforce

I have a requirement to create a child stream from parent stream.
In my requirement i just want to create the child stream from parent (main) with only partial content and don't want to branch all whatever there is in main.Can't we work by creating child stream with partial content of main (patent) streams?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a child stream can be only part of the parent; there is a mapping involved: https://www.perforce.com/video-tutorials/understanding-streams-file-mapping

There is also a related concept in which a child stream can be more like a subsetted "view" of the parent; see "virtual streams": https://www.perforce.com/video-tutorials/using-virtual-streams

Comment: Thanks Bryan. One question i have, after  creating a stream from classic deport(consider it as main branch)  we will be working on stream. If suppose when some developer is not ware that streams are in and made checkins in classic deport  mian branch and if we want to get those changes from classic deport to respective streams is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can use `p4 integrate` to propagate changes between the classic depot and the stream, but it's complex. It would be best if the entire team can use the stream.